# How can Viv generate new code based on some user's query?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, ai-design, natural-language-processing

I have been looking into [Viv](http://viv.ai/), an artificial intelligent agent in development. [Here is a demonstration of Viv (by Dag Kittlaus)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rblb3sptgpQ).

Based on what I understand, this AI can generate new code and execute it based on a query from the user.

What I am curious to know is how this AI can learn to generate code based on some query. *What kind of machine learning algorithms are involved in this process?*

One thing I considered is breaking down a dataset of programs by step. For example, here is the code to take an average of 5 terms

1. Add all 5 terms together
2. Divide by 5

Then I would train an algorithm to convert text to code. That is as far as I have figured out. However, I haven't tried anything because I'm not sure where to start.

*Does anybody have any ideas on how Viv is implemented?*

Comment: I was looking into genetic algorithms and things of that sort when I came across this video: [Genetic Algorithms for Automated Source Code Evolution: a C++11 tutorial](https://vimeo.com/52539994) by David Miller, who seems to know what he's doing. I watched like 20 minutes of it. Interesting stuff and he goes step by step with everything.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's based on NLP and statistical models that consider existing codes that are associated with comments/documents. So some paraphrasing models for the comments to cover a wide rage of tests, and some correction models after getting the initial draft of the code. This is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

4 years and 6 months have past since your unanswered question.

That is an eternity in terms of Machine Learning and things have evolved a lot. So I will answer about the present, not the past.

Today, there are some code generating models, like [GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/) and [OpenAi Codex](https://openai.com/blog/openai-codex/) which are based on NLG (Natural Language Generation). The principle is very simple:

1. Make a huge (billions of parameters) model to predict the next "word" (token) in a sequence of text.
2. Train that model with all available data you can find, and it will understand our language and all kinds of concepts, from philosophy to medicine (that's a GPT).
3. Then you fine-tune it to perform well in programming code, specially in a database filled with code comments.

And now you have a highly capable model for code prediction (generation) from a comment (imperative natural language query).

---

There are also other AI strategies for code prediction, like https://www.tabnine.com/